# Mod_rewrite. Redirect url with Special Characters (question marks)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, special-characters, http-status-code-301

I have a website with joomla and I need to redirect (301) some links

They are in this form (index.php?Itemid= identify them - all links that doesn't have this part shouldn't be redirected)

```
/index.php?Itemid=544&catid=331:savona&id=82356:smembramento-dei-cantieri-baglietto-di-varazze-lopposizione-delle-maestranze&option=com_content&view=article
```

This should work

```
RewriteRule ^index.php?Itemid(.*)$ http://www.ligurianotizie.it/archive/index.php?Itemid$1 [L,R=301]
```

But the first ? (question mark) seems to cause problems.

In fact, if *we suppose* that the links are **without** the question mark

```
/index.phpItemid=544&catid=331:savona&id=82356:smembramento-dei-cantieri-baglietto-di-varazze-lopposizione-delle-maestranze&option=com_content&view=article
```

I would use

```
RewriteRule ^index.phpItemid(.*)$ http://www.ligurianotizie.it/archive/index.php?Itemid$1 [L,R=301]
```

and everything is perfect. But unfortunately real links has that question mark, and I have to find a solution.

What I have to do with that question mark?

Answer (score 2):

Is the `?` character escaped? try to add the `NE` (noescape) flag like this:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php?Itemid(.*)$ http://www.ligurianotizie.it/archive/index.php?Itemid$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: I'm really noob and I'm not sure what escaped means. Anyway no, in the links that we have to redirect there are not strange characters. Just simple ?.
THe code you provided seems to be not working (well.. it seems to work only If remove the question mark from the link to be redirected, so not the solution).

Answer (score 0):

The part behind the question mark is the query string.  You can use `RewriteCond`to determine if it is not empty, and based on that make the decision to redirect.

> Note: Query String
>
> The Pattern will not be matched against the query string. Instead, you must use a RewriteCond with the %{QUERY_STRING} variable. You can, however, create URLs in the substitution string, containing a query string part. Simply use a question mark inside the substitution string, to indicate that the following text should be re-injected into the query string. When you want to erase an existing query string, end the substitution string with just a question mark. To combine a new query string with an old one, use the [QSA] flag.

Source: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: I'm noob and I would like to have an example, if possible.

I found this googling.

FROM 
`http://www.example.com/index.php?option=content&link_id={dynamic ID)` 
TO
`http://www.example.com/index.html/content/?id={dynamic ID)`
 
HOW TO 
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=content&link_id={dynamic ID)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.example.com/index.html/content/?id={dynamic ID)? [R=301,L]`

but the code is wrong of course.. error 500 on the server if I use it (there are of course problems with parenthesis)

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Itemid
RewriteRule ^index.php(.*)$ http://www.ligurianotizie.it/archive/index.php$1 [L,R=301]
```

Every link containing "Itemid" will be redirected, the others not.

Comment: WoW! Seems working! Thanks you!
Anyway I'm doing some test to check if everything is ok!